# The text associated with this error code could not be found. Cannot find a Resource with the XXX

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Im developing a UWP application. In OnLaunch method i add Resources (about 25)

```
 App.Current.Resources.Add(AAA, SomeHexColor);
 App.Current.Resources.Add(BBB, SomeHexColor);
 App.Current.Resources.Add(CCC, SomeHexColor);
 App.Current.Resources.Add(DDD, SomeHexColor);
```

then I use `em in my App.xaml like ApplicationResoures

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonBackgroundPrimaryColor" Color="{StaticResource AAA}" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonForegroundPrimaryColor" Color="{StaticResource BBB}" />
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarButtonForegroundPointerOverPrimaryColor" Color="{StaticResource CCC}" />
```

Time to time I get crash reports like

The text associated with this error code could not be found. Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key CCC [Line: 0 Position: 0]

However I was not be able to reproduce this crash on dev environment?

What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: Why aren't you creating the resources in the `App.xaml` file itself? The problem might be that your app is trying to use the programatically generated resources before you create them. Have you tried testing in `Release` configuration? Apps compiled using `Release` conf are much faster than using `Debug` and may fail because of it.

Comment: @Marian Dolinský because SomeHexColor is not a static variable, it contains some logic to calculate needed color. Also crash happens not on application first page.

Comment: You may try defining the resources with some "placeholder color" and then just changing their color in code. Not the best solution but it may prevent crashes..

Comment: @Marian Dolinský not really a solution, because I also have crash about another color from that list, and that color is static